# using keyword this with multiple constructors in a Class

Tags: java, this, instance-variables, multiple-constructors

I don't understand what happens when you create a Rational object with the constructor Rational(). My book says it will create a Rational object whose value is 0 but internally stored as 0/1. How does this(0) get stored as 0/1? Isn't the default value of the instance variables for both num and den 0?

```
public class Rational{

  public Rational(){
      this(0);
  }

  public Rational(int n){
      this(n,1);
  }

  public Rational(int x, int y){
     num = x; 
     den = y; 
  }

  private int num;
  private int den; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From within a constructor, you can also use the this keyword to call another constructor in the same class. Doing so is called an explicit constructor invocation. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

If you do

```
new Rational()
```

the empty constructor will be called. This constructor will then call the constructor with one argument, i.e.

```
new Rational(0)
```

which again will call

```
new Rational(0,1)
```

That last constructor will then set the instance variables.

---

For further information look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Also interesting:  [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: What would be the disadvantage of having Rational() { this (0,1)   } instead of passing 0 the constructor Rational(int n)? Is it bad practice?

Comment: the only difference is that 'Rational(0,1)' will be called immediately instead of the constructor in between. in this case it doesn't make a difference. but in another case the constructor with one argument could set up some other stuff which would then be skipped.

Answer (score 5):

The term

```
Rational r = new Rational();
```

calls upon

```
public Rational(){
    this(0);
}
```

which calls upon

```
public Rational(int 0){
    this(0,1);
}
```

which calls upon

```
public Rational(int 0, int 1){
   num = 0; 
   den = 1; 
}
```

which means your final object will be Rational(0,1);

Comment: Thanks! I was stumped for the longest time. It turned out to be a simple answer.

Comment: No problem, it can be confusing if one isn't used to seeing the "this()" constructor call :)

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the current object.

**But**

`this()` will call current class constructor that is default constructor.

`this(val)` will call class constructor with one argument...

`this(val1,val2)` call class constructor with two argument...

now if you call `this()` only but you have written you constructor in such way where you might have called other this(withArg). like below..so you can write nested way too.

```
public Rational(){
    this(0);
}
```

**1) The this keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.**

```
public Rational(int num, int den){
     this.num = num; 
     this.den = deb; 
  }
```

**2) this() can be used to invoked current class constructor.**

```
   public Rational(int num, int den){
             this(num);
             this.den = deb; 
          }
```

**3)The this keyword can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly).**

```
public Rational(){
        this.someMethod();
    }
```